# "Access is denied", only when trying to run script over telnet

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, telnet, batch

I have a batch script that restarts a Windows Service with:

```
Net stop <servicename>
Net start <servicename>
```

I got around having to manually run it as Admin by creating a shortcut to it and marking this shortcut to always run as Admin.

By then turning off the need for manual confirmation when running it, I was able to run it as a normal (non-admin) user from the the command line.

When I run it via telnet however (with exactly the same user), I get an "Access is denied" error.

I get this error regardless of which commands are in the batch script, but I am also unable to run the 'Net stop/start' commands individually outside the script because of permissions errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to modify the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy registry key. [More info here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754102%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)